# What would cause an element to display properly in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have a page that I added modals in. Now the footer will not display the grey background. This problem is not affecting other pages. And everything functions fine. The only challenge is the backround image not displaying.

**|| Chrome on left || --------------------------------------- || Firefox on right ||**
[image: comparison]

The link is http://www.ios3d.com/dental-equipment/dental-mill.aspx

I had this error before and I was missing a closing div. I threw in a div before the footer and that is when I recall it being fixed for Firefox, which I know is sloppy but it needed to be functional while I refactor.

The code for that page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
  <meta name="viewport" id="view" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <title>Dental Mill - Open Source Dental Milling Unit</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="dental mill, milling unit, dental equipment, milling unit, milling solution" />
  <meta name="Description" content="The TS150 dental mill is a fast, efficient and affordable open-source milling unit featuring a powerful air-driven 150,000 RPM spindle." />
<!-- Styles and Scripts
================================================ -->
<!--#include file="/_includes/template/head-styles-scripts.html" -->  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/orbit-1.2.3.css"> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.js"></script> 
  <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
      .timer { display: none !important; }
      div.caption { background:transparent; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);zoom: 1; }
    </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <link href="http://www.glidewelldental.com/apps/InteractiveAnimation/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <style>
    #iama-1 { width: 80%; max-width: 1000px; margin: 20px auto; border: 2px solid #444; }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1250px) { #iama-1 { width: 90%; } }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 500px) { #iama-1 { width: 100%; margin: 20px 0; border: none; border-top: 2px solid #444; border-bottom: 2px solid #444; } }

    .nav-button p { color: #fff; }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 767px) { #millDemo { display: none; } }
  </style>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://www.glidewelldental.com/applications/Glidewell.HTML5/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.glidewelldental.com/applications/Glidewell.HTML5/js/respond.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script>
    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
      $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
      });
    }
    preload([
      '/images/products/mill/slider/dentist.jpg',
      '/images/products/mill/slider/side.jpg',
      '/images/products/mill/slider/before.jpg',
      '/images/products/mill/slider/after.jpg',
      '/images/products/mill/slider/radio.jpg'
    ]);
  </script>

  <!-- Run the plugin -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#featured').orbit();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<!-- Header
================================================ -->
<!--#include file="/_includes/template/header.html" -->  

<!-- Region 3 Wrap -->
  <div class="container region3wrap">  
    <!-- Content Top -->  
    <div class="row content_top">
      <div class="nine columns">
        <ul class="breadcrumbs">
          <li><a href="/dental-scanning/index.aspx" title="Dental Scan Solution">IOS Solution</a></li>
          <li class="current"><a href="/dental-equipment/dental-mill.aspx" title="Dental Mill Solution">TS150 Milling Solution</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content Top -->
  </div>
<!-- End Region 3 Wrap -->


<!-- Region 4 Wrap -->
  <div class="container region4wrap">
    <div class="row maincontent">    
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="page_title">      
          <div class="row">   
            <div class="twelve columns">
              <h1>TS150<sup>&trade;</sup> In-Office Milling Solution</h1><br>  
              <h2>Affordable Same-Day Dentistry</h2>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </div><!-- end of page_title-->
      </div>
      <!-- Main Content -->      
      <div class="eight columns">

        <!-- Begin Article -->
        <div class="row">    
          <div class="twelve columns"> 
            <p style="font-size: 1.3em;">
              The TS150<sup>&trade;</sup> Mill provides convenient milling that could reduce your turnaround time to fewer than three hours. The TS150 is a fast, efficient and affordable open-source milling unit featuring a powerful air-driven 150,000 RPM spindle. Its orbital precision milling strategy provides excellent marginal integrity. Use the TS150 to mill materials such as Obsidian<sup>&trade;</sup>, Lava<sup>&trade;</sup> Ultimate and BruxZir<sup>&reg;</sup> Solid Zirconia.
            </p>  

            <div id="millDemo">
              <a href="#" data-reveal-id="millAnimation">
                <img src="/images/products/mill/watchdemo.jpg" />
              </a>   
            </div>

          </div>   
        </div>
        <!-- End  Article -->   

        <!-- Begin Article -->
        <div class="row">         
          <div class="twelve columns">     
            <div class="article_content">  

              <!-- Main Slider --> 
              <div id="cbp-fwslider" class="cbp-fwslider">
                <ul>
<!-- // // // // // // // // // // -->          
                  <li><div><img src="/images/products/mill/slider/dentist.jpg" alt="Dental Mill restorations right in your office" title="Dental Mill restorations right in your office" /></div></li>
<!-- // // // // // // // // // // -->          
                  <li><div><img src="/images/products/mill/slider/side.jpg" alt="Same-day, precise milling from your digital impression" title="Same-day, precise milling from your digital impression"/></div></li>
<!-- // // // // // // // // // // -->          
                  <li><div><img src="/images/products/mill/slider/before.jpg" alt="Pre-operative photo of tooth to be restored" title="Pre-operative photo of tooth to be restored"/></div></li>
<!-- // // // // // // // // // // -->          
                  <li><div><img src="/images/products/mill/slider/after.jpg" alt="Obsidian crown milled in under 20 minutes" title="Obsidian crown milled in under 20 minutes"/></div></li>
<!-- // // // // // // // // // // -->          
                  <li><div><img src="/images/products/mill/slider/radio.jpg" alt="Radiograph shows crown seated with excellent marginal integrity" title="Radiograph shows crown seated with excellent marginal integrity" /></div></li>
<!-- // // // // // // // // // // -->          
                </ul>
              </div> <!-- end of cbp-fwslider -->
              <!-- End Main Slider -->

            </div> <!-- end article_content -->  
          </div> <!-- end twelve columns-->
        </div> <!-- end row -->
        <!-- End  Article -->   

        <!-- Begin Article -->
        <div class="row" id="materials">    
          <div class="twelve columns">
            <hr>   
          </div>  

          <div class="twelve columns">
            <h2 class="article_title">Materials</h2>        
          </div>  

          <div class="twelve columns textCenter">
            <img src="/images/products/mill/blocks.png" alt="blocks">
          </div>  

          <div class="six columns">
            <img src="/images/logos/obsidian.gif" alt="obsidian">
            <hr>
            <p>Obsidian<sup>&trade;</sup> lithium silicate ceramic is a new glass ceramic material indicated for the fabrication of full-contour crowns, 3-unit anterior bridges, veneers, inlays and onlays. Unlike layered ceramic or porcelain-fused-to-metal restorations, Obsidian ceramic restorations are resistant to chipping due to their monolithic composition and average flexural strength of 373 MPa.</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Exceeds the strength requirements for cemented all-ceramic restorations and can also be bonded when desired</li>
              <li>Resists chipping compared to a layered ceramic or PFM restoration</li>
              <li>Available in all VITA Classical and Bleached shades</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="http://www.glidewelldental.com/dentist/services/all-ceramics-obsidian.aspx" target="_blank" class="button small icon-chevron-right">More Info</a>  
          </div> <!-- end six columns-->

          <div class="six columns">           
            <img src="/images/logos/3m.gif" alt="3m">
            <hr>
            <p>Lava<sup>&trade;</sup> Ultimate Restorative is a resin nano ceramic material that offers amazing esthetics, strength and unique functionality. The impressive durability of resin nano ceramic CAD/CAM material results from its high flexural strength and fracture toughness. Nanotechnology on the inside means a beautiful, long-lasting polish on the outside.</p>
            <ul> 
              <li>Less wear to opposing dentition than glass ceramics</li>
              <li>Absorption of chewing forces which reduces stress</li>
              <li>Fast, no firing and easy to mill</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/3M-ESPE-NA/dental-professionals/products/category/digital-materials/lava-ultimate/" target="_blank" class="button small icon-chevron-right">More Info</a>  
          </div> <!-- end six columns-->

        </div> <!-- end row -->

        <!-- Begin Article -->
        <div class="row">    
          <div class="twelve columns">
            <hr>   
          </div>  
          <!-- Mill Video -->       
          <div class="row">    
            <div class="twelve columns">
              <h4 class="video_title">IOS FastDesign Tutorial: Milling the Restoration with the TS-150 Chairside Mill</h4>          
            </div>  
            <!-- Video -->  
            <div class="twelve columns video_container">                 
              <iframe style="scrolling:no; frameborder:0; background-color: transparent;" id="video-player" src="http://www.glidewelldental.com/applications/glidewell.video/embed.aspx?id=IOSFD5&poster=assets/ios-fastdesign-tutorial-milling-the-restoration-with-the-ts-150-chairside-mill.jpg" align="top" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>    
            </div>
            <!-- end of Video -->  
          </div>
        <!-- end of Mill video-->          
        </div>
        <!-- End  Article -->  
      </div>
      <!-- End Main Content -->


      <!-- Sidebar Left -->
      <div class="four columns sidebar-right">  
        <div id="sidebar-product-image" class="sidebar-widget">                  
          <h3>TS150 Mill</h3>                                
          <img src="/images/products/mill360.jpg" alt="Dental Mill" title="Dental Mill"/>
        </div>
        <!-- product links and Call to action
        ================================================ -->
        <!--#include file="/_includes/template/product-pages/product-links-contact-rep.html" -->  
      </div> 
      <!-- End Sidebar Right -->                     
    </div> <!-- end row-->
<!-- // // // // // // // // // // -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <hr/>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- // // // // // // // // // // -->       
  </div>
<!-- End Region 4 Wrap -->



</div> <!-- added to test -->

<!-- Footer
================================================ -->
<!--#include file="/_includes/template/footer.html" -->  



<!-- Back To Top -->
  <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
<!-- End Back To Top -->
<!-- Initialize JS Plugins -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="/javascripts/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/_includes/analytics/google-analytics.js"></script>


<!-- For Animation of the Milling Machine
================================================ -->
<div id="millAnimation" class="reveal-modal twelve columns" style="background-image: none; background-attachment: scroll; width: 90%; padding: 30px; top: 100px; margin-left: -45%;">
  <div id="iama-1" class="iama-context">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <nav>
      <p class="menu-button">Menu</p>
      <ul></ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div> 

<script src="http://www.glidewelldental.com/apps/InteractiveAnimation/js/build.iama.0.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
  var iamaConfig = {
    data : '/json/animation.js',
    context : $('#iama-1')
  };
</script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.cbpFWSlider.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
  /*
  - how to call the plugin:
  $( selector ).cbpFWSlider( [options] );
  - options:
  {
  // default transition speed (ms)
  speed : 500,
  // default transition easing
  easing : 'ease'
  }
  - destroy:
  $( selector ).cbpFWSlider( 'destroy' );
  */
  $( '#cbp-fwslider' ).cbpFWSlider();

  } );
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari and Chrome use [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit), Firefox does not.

You have a css attribute defined for all elements:

```
*
{
    ....
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    ....
}
```

Which is causing your problem. If you remove this attribute, it fixes your problem, but I'm not sure if there's another reason you have this attribute and so I'm not sure if this will lead to other problems.

Another fix is to try to overwrite this only for the necessary elements. I noticed by playing around that you can do this just by adding this css to the body:

```
body
{
    -webkit-backface-visiblity: visible !important;
}
```

However, since the body is at the root of most of your HTML elements, this could also be obtrusive. And this is even more obtrusive if this css is shared across multiple files. If this is true, you may want to add a class to the body and then do something like..

```
body.backface_visible
{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Good catch. I spent a while looking at it but couldn't see it.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's even it. It's a property of `*`. *shakes fist at Inspect Element* In style.css: `*{margin:0;padding:0;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;zoom:0}`

Comment: True, but if you wanted to just remove it for that div, you could just override it for the one div...was trying to be unobtrusive to the rest of his css

Comment: Thank you @CameronAskew , but not sure where I may have applied this incorrectly. As you can see in [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/ydFZFD3), I applied that class but the footer is still not showing up as grey in Safari nor Chrome.

Comment: @ChristianTernus, thanks for the input. Are you suggesting to add that code?

Comment: @JGallardo You're correct, it's not enough to just add that css class - I'll edit my answer in a few minutes to be more correct & complete.

Comment: @CameronAskew You can do it with `!important`, I believe.

Comment: @ChristianTernus unfortunately that still did not work. I Threw in a inline style with matching color in the meantime.

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised -- Cameron's fix worked for me using the inspector.

Comment: @ChristianTernus Yeah it fixes it because it removes the attribute from * (or all elements). But if it is just removed from the div and still applies to the body, it still doesn't show correctly.

Comment: @CameronAskew, ok that fixed it for Safari. But not chrome. So i tried a suggestion that was in your answer previously and applied `!important` and now working. Will use this until I refactor to see why only this page was affected.